# 'Proper' method for using Action query from form

Tags: php, forms, crud

This is a very simple question, and most likely requires a very simple answer. I am pulling data from a MYSQL database, and constructing a table using the retrieved data. I am constructing a CRUD table, having the last two columns being 'edit' and 'delete'. The form I am constructing the final two columns will look something like this:

**The following is found in Welcome.php:**

```
<form action="delete.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="ptest"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

**However, should I make the form's action call the current page instead?**

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" value="ptest"/>
<input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>
</form>
```

I'm very new to PHP and I want to ensure that I am following proper protocol. If this is more an opinion than anything else, please at least leave me your professional opinions.

Thank you very much,

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't.
There is not a strict standard.

Being a newbie, you may find that separate file for the each action easier to understand. So, go for it.
With more experience you will find that having all actions in a single file makes the code shorter and more convenient.

What you have to have in a separate file - is a form itself.
So, you'll be able to use the same form for adding new record, editing existing one and to show submit errors.

Here is an example of one-pager. It does not delete though but can give you a general idea.
It lets you add, edit and browse records.

the code

```
<?  
mysql_connect(); 
mysql_select_db("new"); 
$table = "test"; 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { //form handler part: 
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
  if ($id = intval($_POST['id'])) { 
    $query="UPDATE $table SET name='$name' WHERE id=$id"; 
  } else { 
    $query="INSERT INTO $table SET name='$name'"; 
  } 
  mysql_query($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query); 
  header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  
  exit;  
}  
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) { //listing part: 
  $LIST=array(); 
  $query="SELECT * FROM $table";  
  $res=mysql_query($query); 
  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) $LIST[]=$row; 
  include 'list.php'; 
} else { // form displaying part: 
  if ($id=intval($_GET['id'])) { 
    $query="SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id=$id";  
    $res=mysql_query($query); 
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
    foreach ($row as $k => $v) $row[$k]=htmlspecialchars($v); 
  } else { 
    $row['name']=''; 
    $row['id']=0; 
  } 
  include 'form.php'; 
}  
?>
```

The templates
form.php

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$row['name']?>"><br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$row['id']?>">
<input type="submit"><br>
<a href="?">Return to the list</a>
</form>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

and list.php

```
<? include TPL_TOP ?>
<a href="?id=0">Add item</a>
<? foreach ($LIST as $row): ?>
<li><a href="?id=<?=$row['id']?>"><?=$row['name']?></a>
<? endforeach ?>
<? include TPL_BOTTOM ?>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this line: ' if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') '

Also, wouldn't I want to give the submit button a value and add a line at the top saying ' if(!isset($_POST['submitvalue']))

Comment: @Evan excellent questions. 1. Because we are having all the code in a single file, we have to distinguish regular calls to this script from calls when it acts as a form action. Thus this line is used for the latter one. 2. I am using just id to distinguish actions. if id=0 - it's add, if id is positive number - then it's edit. However, for the delete you will need such a field. Though I prefer a hidden form field named "delete" with id as a value.